How to only authorize import modules listed in the import map?
How to only authorize dependencies listed in the imports block of the deno.json file?
This example should not work when I run deno run -A main.ts because the dependency is not listed in the imports block.
deno.json:
{
  "imports": {}
}

main.ts:
import { fib } from "jsr:@phocks/fib"; // Error not listed in deno.json

console.log(fib(3)); 

However, this example must work when I run deno run -A main.ts because the dependency is listed in the imports block.
deno.json:
{
  "imports": {
    "fibonacci": "jsr:@phocks/fib"
  }
}

main.ts:
import { fib } from "fibonacci"; // import from deno.json

console.log(fib(3)); 


Allowing/denying by specifier is not how Deno's import permission model works — imports can only be restricted by their associated network host. Additionally: the runtime argument -A (short equivalent for --allow-all) allows all permissions… using it allows all import hosts. Please be sure to read through the entire manual section Security and Permissions, then [edit] the question to clarify (or close if it is no longer relevant).
